# Open a tray application with VBScript

Tags: vbscript

With VBScript, is there a way to open an application and have it maximize its window when its default behavior is to minimize to the tray?

I have an app that opens to the tray and does not show its login screen. I am trying to automate the login process using VBScript and `SendKeys`. I know this isn't secure since anyone can view the script but that isn't a concern.

Is there a way to open an app and then make it display its GUI? I also need to make sure that the app gets focus so that `SendKeys` works.

I know how to open the app. The problem is getting the app to show its login screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Dim oWsh : Set oWsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oWsh.Run("prog.exe", 1, False)
WScript.Sleep 500
oWsh.AppActivate "Prog Title"  ' text in window title of 'prog.exe'
oWsh.SendKeys "first Command"
' ...additional SendKeys commands
```

References: [Run Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=VS.84%29.aspx) and [SendKeys Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28v=VS.84%29.aspx)